# Select items in multiselect dropdown list MVC3 jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-select

How can i set values in a multiselect dropdownlist using jquery.I am using MVC3 Razor view to display the multiselect dropdown  and using http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/ this multiselect plugin.

```
 <div class="editor-field">         
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActionId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ActionsList, new { @class = "multiselect", @multiple = "multiple", @style = "width: 450px;height:300px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActionId)   
</div>
<button onclick="setValues()">Set values </button>
```

In javascript i used the code

```
function setValues() {      
    var valArr = [2, 3, 5];
    var i = 0, size = valArr.length;
    var  $options = $('#ActionId option');
    for (i; i < size; i++) {           
        // $("#ActionId option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", 1); this is also not working
        $("#ActionId option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", true);
    }     
}
```

But the values are not getting selected on the click event of button.
When i refresh the page , the values are getting selected.
How can i overcome this ? i want to set the values in multdropdown list on button click using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to provide field name whose value will be bind by Razor engine to dropdownlist for that you need to provide the property name that you want to bind in dropdown.
Try this out

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActionId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.ActionsList,"AccountID","AccountName"), new { @class = "multiselect", @multiple = "multiple", @style = "width: 450px;height:300px" })
```

where AccountId,AccountName is the property field inside ActionsList
and AccountName values will be show in page and AccountId will be bind on select

In your case check ActionsList and put property name that exist in place of AccountId and AccountName

Comment: But how can i set the selected values on the Dropdownlist?
My dropdown is a multiselect one and i want to set some values as selected.How can i do that?

Comment: This doesn't seem to bind properly onto the view the selected items.  It works fine the other way for binding the selected values to the model but not from the model to the view to show what was previously selected

Answer (score 0):

You can use choosen js to do multiselect functionaily.

Please refer this documentation with demo.

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/